# Eclipse C++ plugin on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu

I 've just installed ubuntu 13.04 Os on my laptop, then I downloaded eclipse Kepler for Java , After that I wanted to install c++ plugin for eclipse. so I typed in the terminal the command "sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt" , and it took a while to complete this process.
But the problem is whenever I open eclipse again, I don't find the c/c++ perspective in eclipse. and it seems as if I haven't installed the CDT, any help please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Uninstall everything
2. Download [Eclipse CDT x86](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-cpp-kepler-R-linux-gtk.tar.gz) or [Eclipse CDT x64](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-cpp-kepler-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)
3. Extract to /usr/lib/eclipse
4. Link /usr/bin/eclipse to /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
5. You should now be able to select the C++ perspective and create C++ projects

Alternatively:

1. Uninstall everything
2. Download [Eclipse Standard x86](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-standard-kepler-R-linux-gtk.tar.gz) or [Eclipse Standard x64](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-standard-kepler-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)
3. Extract to /usr/lib/eclipse
4. Link /usr/bin/eclipse to /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
5. Open Eclipse
6. Help > Install New Software
7. Add the CDT Repository: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler
8. Select CDT and install it